# no pods monitor information in kubernetes(heapster, influxdb, grafana)

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana, heapster

I create heapster, influxdb, grafana to monitor kubernetes , by kubectl create -f ./cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb
file from : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb
I can access grafana, kube status and influxdb (the latter by appending :http to the url ) ,but I cannot access the heapster (get a 404 ), and the grafana can list node monitor information, and no pods monitor information,why?

Comment: You can retrieve the logs per pod with `kubectl logs {pod} {namespace}` That could give you a few pointers

Comment: How did you install? Which command you used to install ? #kubectl ....?

Answer (score 0):

Try exposing the heapster using NodePort.
In heapster.yaml unders spec(service) add a new entry

> ```
> type: NodePort
> ```

The yaml portion should look somethting like this after entry.

> ```
> spec:   
>    type: NodePort   
>    ports:
>    - port: 80
>      targetPort: 8082    
>    selector:
>      k8s-app: heapster
> ```

Then check the services running in your cluster using the following command.

> ```
> kubectl get services -n kube-system
> ```

Find out the port of heapster from service list. It should look something like this.

> 80:32068/TCP

Then access heapster api with cluster_ip:port 

For example:

> ```
> http://192.168.99.100:32068/api/v1/model/namespaces/default/pods/
> ```

You should be able to access the heapster then.